# How To display Weight on Gridview from weight scale in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I am developing weight scale program by serial port communication
but I have do like this.... example:

use put item on scale when my
 app get weight then stop comunicate with scale first get weight set on
 `gridviewrowcolumn` then row change automatically and when user put
 second item on scale comunication start and same procedure do..

here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;


namespace serial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SerialPort _serialPort;         //<-- declares a SerialPort Variable to be used throughout the form
        private const int BaudRate = 9600;   

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            #region Form Load
            try
            {
                //getRawWeight();
                string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();     //<-- Reads all available comPorts
                foreach (var portName in portNames)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(portName);                  //<-- Adds Ports to combobox
                }
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;      
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            #endregion
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_serialPort != null && _serialPort.IsOpen)
                _serialPort.Close();
            if (_serialPort != null)
                _serialPort.Dispose();
            //<-- End of Block

            _serialPort = new SerialPort(comboBox1.Text, BaudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);       //<-- Creates new SerialPort using the name selected in the combobox
            _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPortOnDataReceived;       //<-- this event happens everytime when new data is received by the ComPort
            _serialPort.Open();     //<-- make the comport listen
            textBox1.Text = "Listening on " + _serialPort.PortName + "...\r\n";
        }
        private delegate void Closure();
        private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)     //<-- Makes sure the function is invoked to work properly in the UI-Thread
                BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));     //<-- Function invokes itself
            else
            {
                while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0) //<-- repeats until the In-Buffer is empty
                {
                    string reading = "";
                    reading += string.Format("{0:X2} ", _serialPort.ReadByte());
                    //<-- bytewise adds inbuffer to textbox
                    //string reading = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_serialPort);
                    textBox1.Text = reading.Substring(13);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would open the serial port once and then leave it open until you close your program.  Have you successfully communicated with the scale yet?  Also some devices like scales have their own button that will send data across the serial port each time you push it.  What is wrong with your code?  What does it do as it is written?